# Cubic install is different than original... why?

Tags: package-management, preseed, diff

Making my first steps in automating the installation of Ubuntu. Found the Cubic package being recommended and I'm trying it out at the moment.

One thing I noticed on one of the first runs was that there is a difference in output. Let me explain:

I always choose the minimum installation for Ubuntu and creating a custom ISO with Cubic adds around 40+ extra packages, most visible is Thunderbird, even though I did a next, next, finish in Cubic and changed nothing. After installing the additional packages are just there.

Did I do something wrong, must I figure out which packages have been added and manually disable them, is this a bug in cubic?

If anyone can share any insight that would be great.

Comment: You are right. When you select "Minimal installation" in the Ubuntu installer (a.k.a. Ubiquity), certain packages should not be installed. (Technically, they are supposed to be removed by Ubiquity from your destination disk before it finishes). I tested, and I found some packages are removed (ex. `rhythmbox`) as expected, while others aren't (ex. `thunderbird`). You should open a [bug report for Cubic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cubic) to get this fixed.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, appreciate the effort. I’ll file a bug report with them.

Answer (score 1):

Contacted the Devs and they have applied a fix. Updated to version 2021.09-53. Validated and the issue is resolved.